# build method command in cell and run it in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following command which runs correctly if placed inside a macro in vba:

```
Set elements = doc.getElementsByClassName("media-body")
```

I try to have this command running while taking the information from within a cell. Thus I place

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("media-body")
```

in cell D5 , but when I run:
`Set elements = evaluate("Range(""D5"")"`) it throws an error (Run-time error '424': Object required.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to solve it.  `Excel.Application.Evaluate` only works with a subset of Excel objects.  From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> The following types of names in Microsoft Excel can be used
>   with this method:
>
> Formulas. A1-style references. You can use any
>   reference to a single cell in A1-style notation. All references are
>   considered to be absolute references.
>
> Ranges. You can use the range,
>   intersect, and union operators (colon, space, and comma, respectively)
>   with references. Defined names. You can specify any name in the
>   language of the macro.
>
> External references. You can use the ! operator
>   to refer to a cell or to a name defined in another workbook ? for
>   example, Evaluate("[BOOK1.XLS]Sheet1!A1").
>
> Chart Objects. You can
>   specify any chart object name, such as "Legend", "Plot Area", or
>   "Series 1", to access the properties and methods of that object. For
>   example, Charts("Chart1").Evaluate("Legend").Font.Name returns the
>   name of the font used in the legend.

The reason that you get an error 424 is because `doc` is an object reference in the code you are trying to run from the cell.  `Evaluate` has no clue what `doc` ***is***, because there is no way to set it to an instance from within a cell.

The only way to do anything meaningful with the cell contents in the question would be to parse the code in the cell and basically run it through an VBA-VBA interpreter.

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly what you're after (see the comments), what you'd really like is a way to generically search for HTML elements based on name and type.  I'd approach this by selecting how to search the element name based on a type parameter.  The example below assumes that the target cell (in row `sourceRow` and column `sourceCol`) contains the element name, ie "media-body", and the cell to the right contains its type - i.e. "ClassName".

```
Public Function GetElement(targetSheet As Worksheet, doc As HTMLDocument, _
                           sourceRow As Long, sourceCol As Long) As IHTMLElement
    With targetSheet
        'Get the element name from the passed cell.
        Dim elementName As String
        elementName = .Cells(sourceRow, sourceCol)
        'Get the element type from the adjacent cell.
        Dim elementType As String
        elementType = .Cells(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1)
        Select Case elementType
            Case "ClassName"
                Set GetElement = doc.getElementsByClassName(elementName)
            Case "Id"
                Set GetElement = doc.getElementById(elementName)
            Case "Name"
                Set GetElement = doc.getElementsByName(elementName)
            '...
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

This could just as easily be accomplished with a comma delimited string in a single cell - something like "media-body,ClassName", or several other methods but this is the direction I'd go.

Comment: So what you are saying is to have the whole code build in a cell and then run it thru a vba interpreter ? Can you mention a reliable  VBA interpreter ?

Comment: @Andrei - AFAIK, there isn't a VBA interpreter written in VBA - you'd have to write it.

Comment: :( this is smth beyond my vba expertise

Comment: @Andrei - What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I try to build a web scraping template in Excel. My idea is to input inside the cell some generic elements and then have the code perform based on this elements. For example if I have to look inside a page for classname="media-body" I will put this inside a cell and then the code performs accordingly.

Comment: @Andrei - Why not just put `media-body` in the cell then? If you need to select by the type of element, define an `Enum` of element types, put that in an adjacent cell, and use a `Select Case` block to call the appropriate `getElementsBy*` method based type.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you provide an example ? It will spare some time for me , otherwise i have to search the internet. 10x

Comment: Thank you, I will follow it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your:

```
Set elements = evaluate("Range(""D5"")")
```

With:

```
Set elements = Evaluate("D5")
```

Comment: I've tried , but it just sets the value of **elements** to doc.getElementsByClassName("media-body"). It does not run the method .

Comment: IYou need to provide more info, what do you have in the rest of your code ? what do you have inside Cell "D5" ?

Comment: This is part of my code - the other elements of it are general elements with no impact on the problem:`Sub template_scrap()
ie.navigate Range("B3")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

Set doc = ie.document

'This one works
Set elements = doc.getElementsByClassName("media-body")
'This one works also but does not do what i want
'in D5 i have - doc.getElementsByclassname("media-body")
Set elements = Evaluate("D5")
End Sub`

Comment: The page I navigate to is : https://www.techinasia.com/startups?sort=-funding_round_date&country_name%5b%5d=Malaysia